# USBL Hydrophone Array Spacing

Tags: signal-processing

I am trying to design a USBL acoustic pinger location system for a school project. I am struggling to determine if the frequency of the acoustic beacon ping places a constraint on the distances between hydrophones in the array. I have found in one source online that the hydrophones must be less than one half a wavelength apart to be able to implement the phase-comparison method for angle of arrival calculations. Is this the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no.

Larger than that spacing introduces ambiguities in bearing. If the ambiguity can be resolved by other means (by knowledge of the source, or other hydrophones more closely spaced) then the extra receivers will still improve SNR and bearing accuracy.